# react bootstrap table not rendering data without refresh

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap-table

i am using react-redux with react bootstrap table . my UI is given in picture . when i add payment the data is saved in database. i have used componentdidupdate and componentdidUpdate to render the props data . but nothing is working .  the table does not render the data without refresh . please help......................................................................................................

[image: my UI]

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
// import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux'
import { Link } from 'react-router';
import Messages from '../Messages';
import classnames from 'classnames';
import { BootstrapTable, TableHeaderColumn } from 'react-bootstrap-table';
import { getCrmOneCustomer, saveStatus, getCrmStatus } from '../../actions/crmAction';
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
class CrmStatus extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            name: '', shop_name: '', crm_id: '', status: ''
        };

        this.props.dispatch(getCrmOneCustomer(this.props.params.id));
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }


    componentDidMount() {
         this.props.dispatch(getCrmStatus(this.props.params.id));

    }

    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    componentWillReceiveProps(newProps) {
        console.log('componentWillReceiveProps............ from edit');
        console.log(newProps)
        this.setState({
            name: newProps.CrmOne.name,
            shop_name: newProps.CrmOne.shop_name,
            status: newProps.CrmOne.status, 

        })
      }
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    handleChange(event) {
        this.setState({
            [event.target.name]: event.target.value
        });
    }
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var Id = this.props.params.id;
        var obj = {};
        obj["crm_id"] = Id
        obj["name"] = this.state.name
        obj["shop_name"] = this.state.shop_name
        obj["status"] = this.state.status
        console.log(obj)

        this.props.dispatch(saveStatus(obj))
    }
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------

    componentDidUpdate(){

        this.products = this.props.CrmOneStatus
    }

    render() {


        return (
            <div className="container ca-container">

                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-md-12">
                    <h2>CRM Status</h2>


                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="row">
            <div className="col-md-12">

            <div className ="col-md-8">
            <BootstrapTable data={this.products} striped hover pagination={true} search>
            <TableHeaderColumn isKey dataField='name'>Name</TableHeaderColumn>
            <TableHeaderColumn dataField='status'>status</TableHeaderColumn>
            <TableHeaderColumn dataField='createdAt'>Date</TableHeaderColumn>
            </BootstrapTable>
            </div>
            <div className ="col-md-4">
            <h4> Add Payment  </h4>

            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} encType="multipart/form-data">

            <div className="form-group">
                  <label>
                    Name:
               </label>
                  <input disabled type="text" className="form-control" name="name" value={this.state.name} onChange={this.handleChange} placeholder="Zahid Hasan" />
                </div>
                <div className="form-group">
                  <label>
                  shop name:
                </label>
                  <input  type="text" className="form-control" name="shop_name" value={this.state.shop_name} onChange={this.handleChange} placeholder="amount" />
                </div>

              <div className="form-group">
              <label>
              Status:
              </label>
              <textarea  rows="8" cols="50"  type="text" className="form-control" name="status" value={this.state.status} onChange={this.handleChange} placeholder="comment" />
              </div>
              <div className="btn-group" role="group">
              <button type="submit" className="btn btn-success btn-lg">Submit</button>



             </div>
             </form>


             </div>
             </div>
             </div>


            </div>
        );
    }
}
// ======================== REDUX CONNECTORS ========================
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        CrmOne: state.crmCustomer.CrmOne,
        CrmOneStatus: state.crmCustomer.CrmOneStatus
    };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(CrmStatus);
```

Comment: You don't need to assign props to a class variable and pass that on as data, you can easily do `<BootstrapTable data={this.props.CrmOneStatus}`, when you assign your props to the class variable a re-render doesn't happen and you don't see the data

Comment: {this.props.CrmOneStatus} tried that but it does not work

Comment: what do you mean by it doesn't work, is there an error

Comment: no the table data not changes . i have to refresh the page

Comment: Got it, adding an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in constructor i added this

```
this.props.dispatch(getCrmStatus(this.props.params.id));
```

and handle submit

```
this.props.dispatch(getCrmStatus(this.props.params.id));
```

and it works like charm !!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: any explaination what is it doing internally ? how this fix is solving the problem ? I have a similar problem my table data is coming from parent props but it is showing error "nextProps.data.slice is not a function "

Answer (score 0):

You are making a request to fetch the data in the `componentDidMount` function which is only executed once when the component has mounted, i.e the reason it works when you refresh the page, However you should get the data whenever the props change, i.e. use the `componentWillReceiveProps` function. Also you don't need to assign the props to the class variable, you can directly use the props to as data.

```
class CrmStatus extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            name: '', shop_name: '', crm_id: '', status: ''
        };

        this.props.dispatch(getCrmOneCustomer(this.props.params.id));
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }


    componentDidMount() {
         this.props.dispatch(getCrmStatus(this.props.params.id));

    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(newProps) {
        console.log('componentWillReceiveProps............ from edit');
        console.log(newProps)
        if(nextProps.params.id !== this.props.params.id) {
             this.props.dispatch(getCrmStatus(nextProps.params.id));
        }
        this.setState({
            name: newProps.CrmOne.name,
            shop_name: newProps.CrmOne.shop_name,
            status: newProps.CrmOne.status, 

        })
      }
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    handleChange(event) {
        this.setState({
            [event.target.name]: event.target.value
        });
    }
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var Id = this.props.params.id;
        var obj = {};
        obj["crm_id"] = Id
        obj["name"] = this.state.name
        obj["shop_name"] = this.state.shop_name
        obj["status"] = this.state.status
        console.log(obj)

        this.props.dispatch(saveStatus(obj))
    }
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------


    render() {


        return (
            <div className="container ca-container">

                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-md-12">
                    <h2>CRM Status</h2>


                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="row">
            <div className="col-md-12">

            <div className ="col-md-8">
            <BootstrapTable data={this.props.CrmOneStatus} striped hover pagination={true} search>
            <TableHeaderColumn isKey dataField='name'>Name</TableHeaderColumn>
            <TableHeaderColumn dataField='status'>status</TableHeaderColumn>
            <TableHeaderColumn dataField='createdAt'>Date</TableHeaderColumn>
            </BootstrapTable>
            </div>
            <div className ="col-md-4">
            <h4> Add Payment  </h4>

            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} encType="multipart/form-data">

            <div className="form-group">
                  <label>
                    Name:
               </label>
                  <input disabled type="text" className="form-control" name="name" value={this.state.name} onChange={this.handleChange} placeholder="Zahid Hasan" />
                </div>
                <div className="form-group">
                  <label>
                  shop name:
                </label>
                  <input  type="text" className="form-control" name="shop_name" value={this.state.shop_name} onChange={this.handleChange} placeholder="amount" />
                </div>

              <div className="form-group">
              <label>
              Status:
              </label>
              <textarea  rows="8" cols="50"  type="text" className="form-control" name="status" value={this.state.status} onChange={this.handleChange} placeholder="comment" />
              </div>
              <div className="btn-group" role="group">
              <button type="submit" className="btn btn-success btn-lg">Submit</button>



             </div>
             </form>


             </div>
             </div>
             </div>


            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry still does not works . have to refresh , i have used the code you given